# YAML_FILE_ERROR: did not find expected key

Tags: json, yaml, aws-codebuild, pyyaml

I tried to run Buildspec using aws codeBuild and trying to generate process.json file on-fly using jq command. But it gives an error while executing and build goes failed..

```
build: 
              commands:
                - cp $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/qe/performance/* apache-jmeter-5.2/bin/
                - cd apache-jmeter-5.2/bin/
                - DATE=`date "+%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S"`
                - aws s3 cp $DATE-Report s3://$JMeterScanResultBucket/${ProjectName}/$DATE --recursive
                - jq -n --arg appname "$appname" '{apps: [ {project: wsg, issuetype: "Test Execution", summary: "Test Execution for junit Execution"}]}' > process.json
```

however, I have received following error: Line 20 goes to above "jq" command

```
DOWNLOAD_SOURCE 
Failed
YAML_FILE_ERROR: did not find expected key at line 20
```

Comment: I wrote an answer. I'm not paid for it. It would at least be nice to let me know if it was helpful or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A colon plus a space (or newline) in YAML means it's a key-value pair in a mapping:

```
key: value
```

Your jq command contains several colons followed by spaces.

Since you want a single string, you must quote it.

There are several ways to do that in YAML.

Single or double quoting wouldn't be ideal here because the string contains both quote types.

A [folded block scalar](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html#folded) is probably the best solution here. Newlines will be folded together as spaces.

```
- >
  jq -n --arg appname "$appname"
  '{apps: [ {project: wsg, issuetype: "Test Execution",
  summary: "Test Execution for junit Execution"}]}'
  > process.json
```

An alternative would be the [literal block scalar](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html#literal), where you have to escape the linebreak like in a shell script:

```
- |
  jq -n --arg appname "$appname" \
  '{apps: [ {project: wsg, issuetype: "Test Execution", \
  summary: "Test Execution for junit Execution"}]}' \
  > process.json
```

Comment: Tinita..Thank you very much for your prompt response. I, however, started working on other priorities. But i have just tested this functionality and it actually work while defining to distinguish the lines. Thanks a ton!

Comment: If the answer fixes your problem, you should accept it.